# Combine asp-route-id with asp-route-all-data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Is there any way to make this work?

```
<a class="btn btn-info" asp-action="ActionName" asp-route-id="@item.ID"
                       asp-all-route-data="parms" >Action</a>
```

This generates the following link:

```
sitename.com/controller/action?parm1=parm1&parm2=parm2
```

etc.  I want it to generate this:

```
sitename.com/controller/action/{id}?parm1=parm1&parm2=parm2
```

It seems as though you cannot combine the route-id with asp-route-all-data.  It is a link on a table and so my ID changes with each row, the rest of the filters (searchstrings, pages, sorts, etc) do not change.  Would save a lot of copying and pasting if this would work.

While writing this I realized I could probably make a Viewmodel with a Dictionary of items AND an IEnumerable of my Model, rather than just using my model as is.  Is there any other (simpler) way of making this work?

Comment: One option might be to include a `{ id, "" }` item in `parms`, and then in your loop update it in each iteration -  `parms["id"] = item.Id;` (and delete the `asp-route-id`)

Comment: That worked Stephen.  Good suggestion.  I think of all the questions I have asked on SO you have answered like 90% of them.  I still havent found an answer to my yahoo Oauth2 questions if you have any thoughts on that stuff.  hehe.  Thanks again

Comment: It works but its not that elegant. I'm not sure why they chose not to merge the any `asp-route-{property}` into the `asp-all-route-data` dictionary and will take a look at the source code next week.

Answer (score 4):

Putting the "asp-all-route-data" attribute before "asp-route-id" solves the problem.

```
<a class="btn btn-info" asp-action="ActionName" 
        asp-all-route-data="parms"             
        asp-route-id="@item.ID">Action</a>
```

And generates the following link:

```
sitename.com/controller/action/{id}?parm1=parm1&parm2=parm2
```